# django production server allow user to access requirements.txt and other file like manage.py

Tags: python, django, nginx

I find a big security breaches server allow user to access files
example:
a user can access https://example.com/app_directory/requirements.txt
and the worst is i can download all file.py by doing https://example.com/app_directory/site/manage.py

Content-Encoding deflate can be the cause.

How can i fix that?

nginx conf

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com; 
    root /home/user/app_project/;

    location /static {
        alias /home/user/app_project/app_name/app_name/staticfiles;
    }
    
    location /media {
        alias /home/user/app_project/app_name/media;
    }
        
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            break;
        }
    }
        

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: Which server and what configuration are you using. This is a configuration issue in your front server and Django has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If you have set your project root or the application to be the static directory or the media directory then that is your mistake in configuration and Django cannot do anything about that. Otherwise if you are just not describing it properly (To not reveal the security flaw) then you are not reporting it to the correct platform, have a look at [Reporting bugs and requesting features](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/bugs-and-features/#reporting-bugs-and-requesting-features) please report it to  security@djangoproject.com

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby i'm using nginx server and i paste my conf file below

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I think the cause is django not throwing error if route not match and that can allow a malicious user  to access project files but just if they know the location

Comment: remove the root from the nginx config

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby  i removed the root and that work thanks